# what value C# set property return?

Tags: c#, properties

I just write "strange" code, but the build success.
Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter();
// s="@aa"
var s = (p1.ParameterName = "@aa");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p1.ParameterName = "@aa",p1.Value = "aaa");
```

### so i wonder why the set property return value "@aa"?

I don't think this is SQL Parameters issue,so i write other sample code:

```
    TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
    // result="testName"
    var result = (t1.Name = "testName");
    string returnName = t1.TestName(t1.Name = "testName");
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho i don't think so. And i write another code is :            TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
            // result="testName"
            var result = (t1.Name = "testName");
            string returnName = t1.TestName(t1.Name = "testName");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that's the line you find strange:

```
var s = (p1.ParameterName = "@aa");
```

From C# spec:

> **7.17.1 Simple assignment**
>
> *(...)*
>
> The result of a *simple assignment expression* is the value assigned to the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value.

Which means assignment operator returns the value that was assigned.

Comment: That or the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p1.ParameterName = "@aa",p1.Value = "aaa");` line which is basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain "....always classified as a value". Classified as a value NOT mean Value types.Right?

Comment: @James: Correct. The intention of "classified as a value" is intended to indicate that the thing is not classified as a variable. For instance, `a = ((b = c) = 10);` is not legal because `(b=c)` is a *value*, and not a *variable*, and therefore you cannot assign 10 to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value you can still use the assigned value, so using your 2nd example you did something very similar to this:

```
TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
// result="testName"
t1.Name = "testName"
var result = (t1.Name);
t1.Name = "testName"
string returnName = t1.TestName(t1.Name);
```

and in your first example you did pretty much the same as this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter();
// s="@aa"
p1.ParameterName = "@aa";
var s = (p1.ParameterName);

p1.ParameterName = "@aa";
p1.Value = "aaa";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p1.ParameterName, p1.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Properties combine aspects of both fields and methods. To the user of an object, a property appears to be a field, accessing the property requires the same syntax. To the implementer of a class, a property is one or two code blocks, representing a get accessor and/or a set accessor. The code block for the get accessor is executed when the property is read; the code block for the set accessor is executed when the property is assigned a new value. A property without a set accessor is considered read-only. A property without a get accessor is considered write-only. A property that has both accessors is read-write.

You can find further information from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question... And it's a clear copy-paste from MSDN.